# How to control Unity Animation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As far as I know, there are ways to manage Animation

Immediately,

1. Managing in the form of objects.
2. Managing with Sprite Images.

Is it effective to manage animations 
in object format to manage character's joints in 2D animation?

What should I do to make it easier for me to understand Unity Animation?

As a beginner, we need a lot of data. I need your help. Help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to explain the animation by manipulating GameObjects.

You need to add an Animator component to the GameObject you wish to animate. The animator component needs an animator controller. You also need to create an animation clip which represents an animation.(Animation controller is automatically created when you create an animation clip)

Now, to get started with animation you need to focus on animation clips. After you add an animation clip, you can record an animation into it. You do this by hitting the record button in the Animation window. While recording, any changes made to the GameObject will be recorded into the animation clip. (For example, you might move your GameObject). Any such change will create a key frame in the Animation timeline. The time point where key frame should be created can be changed.

Unity will interpolate the changes between two keyframes automatically.
However, there is also an animation curve which allows you to define how changes are applied between time points.

After you record animations you can define how transitions between different animations are made in the Animator Window.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunably I am not really sure what your question is about?

For question this might be helpful:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PuXUCX21jJU

Usually you have a Image File with the animation movements of your 2D Image object and using the "Sprite Editor" to cut them out for Unity.

You then add this Clip on a Animimation Component to be added to your "GameObject".

Since this is a "C#" question, maybe you want to know how to access this Compnent. The best is to use it in the "Init()" and add:

var anim = GetComponent();

Now you can use the "Animation" Component to play the configured Animation Clips.

I hope this helps you a little bit.